# Safari browser test execution is too slow after updating Appium 1.15.0, Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1.2 version

Tags: appium, appium-ios, safari-web-inspector

Safari browser test execution is too slow after updating Appium 1.15.0, Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1.2 version

It was working fine in Appium 1.13.0, Xcode 10.3 and iOS 12.x version

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular part (line of code) or just launching safari which is slow? I am running on safari in osx 12x and 13

Comment: Safari browser is launched successfully.  Object identification and execution is very slow after launched browser. Same script is working very fast in iOS 12x version

Comment: Yes , I detect reduce in speed for native for iOS 13.1. Have you try enabling useFirstMatch to see if it helps to improve ?

Comment: I have tried useFirstMatch option but it is not working